# Unmet Peer Dependency Error

Tags: angular, npm

> npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of
>   @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer  dependencies yourself.

Earlier I installed angular cli by using npm install -g @angular/cli then i uninstalled and installed npm install -g @angular/cli@latest. Now many earlier packages are not compatible, so I again uninstalled and installed angular cli using command npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.0. Now when i was trying to download various packages, I am unable to. I tried downloading bootstrap using npm install bootstrap --save, the below warning occurs:

> **npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer  dependencies yourself.**

Please help me how I can start fresh and have all packages intact.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this issue, you'll need to install it via NPM.  Not sure why it doesn't get automatically installed.

`npm install @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 --save`